# Cypress select li and click on child span

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I am trying to select li and click/check on span which is checkbox but, can't do that.

Here, following I tried.

```
<div id="list-widget">
    <ul class="tree">
    <li class="tree-switcher-close"> .... </li>
    <li class="tree-switcher-close">     
      <span class="tree-checkbox">  //I want to Click on this
        <div class="container">
         <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </div>
      </span>
      <span title="abc Account">
        <span class="tree-title">abc Account</span>
      </span>
     </li>
     <li class="tree-switcher-close"> 
       <span class="tree-checkbox"></span>
       ....
     </li>
     <li class="tree-switcher-close"> 
      <span class="tree-checkbox"></span>
      .... 
     </li>
    </ul>
```

Here, in above code I want to select li where **"abc account"** and once found want to **click on span** which have **class tree-checkbox**. So, I tried.

```
cy.get('div[id*="list-widget"]')
        .find('li')
        .contains('abc Account')
        .get('.tree-checkbox').click({force: true});
```

But, it says there are multiple elements found. above code find the li which have **contains('abc Account')** but, can't span within that li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is with `.get('.tree-checkbox')`. It "forgets" all the preceding path, so you might as well start with `cy.get('.tree-checkbox')` and of course that gives multiple elements.

Change that to `.find('.tree-checkbox')`.

Also combine `li` and `abc Account` in one selector, because `.contains('abc Account')` by itself takes you to the `<span class="tree-title">abc Account</span>` which has no `tree-checkbox`.

```js
cy.get('div[id="list-widget"]')
  .find('li:contains("abc Account")')
  .find('.tree-checkbox')
  .click({force:true});
```

Other variation that works (but is more verbose)

```js
cy.get('div[id*="list-widget"]')
  .find('li')
  .contains('abc Account')
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .find(".tree-checkbox")
  .click({force:true})
```